# What folders of my playframework project can I delete?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Can I just delete the folders bin, data, precompiled, and tmp without having any issues? Will they just be regenerated again next time? I don't mind losing attachment files, images, etc in the data folder since I am cleaning my DB anyway. I am using play 1.2.4.

Comment: why not use `clean` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep the following.

```
app
conf
public
lib      <-- maybe empty
```

The rest should regenerate, or generate when you run play deps.